# Calling function from another php file

Tags: php

I have 2 file

file1.php

```
<?php
      Class A
      {
          public static function _test
          {
          }
      }
      function get_sql($id)
      {
      }
      function get_data($ids)
      {
      }
?>
```

In file2.php I've written

```
require_once('file1.php');
  $a = get_sql($id);
```

Why I cannot call the function and get my result??

Comment: did you tried searching ?

Comment: "Calling function from another php file" -- before calling it from "another file" - could you get it running from the same file? Why do you think running from another file is something different?

Comment: Its against OOPs paradigm

Comment: @swapnesh: it's has nothing to do with *paradygm*, but with syntax

Comment: @zerkms lol thx for the info and the way u mentioned _paradygm_ :)

Comment: @swapnesh: and a person who uses "u" instead of "you" points me to my grammar errors. *sighs*

Comment: get_sql() is return function?

Comment: @Mani: "is return" --- what does it even mean? Guys, seriously, stop inventing terms on the fly.

Comment: Create a object and refer a method of the class by
`$a = new A();
$a->get_sql($id);`

Comment: Both functions get_* are outside the class scope, guys

Comment: Make sure the path is correct. As is, both files should be in the same directory. Additionally, where is the value of `$id` set?

Comment: $id is the value to be passed

Answer (score 0):

try this in file1.php

```
<?php
  Class A {
     public static function _test {
     }
     function get_sql($id) {
        echo $id;
     }
     function get_data($ids) {
     }
  }
?>
```

In file2.php first require the file and then code this

```
require_once('file1.php');
$a = new A();
$a->get_sql($id);
```

OR send static value in function

```
$a->get_sql(5);
```

This is your first mistake in your code

```
public static function _test{
    }
  } //this bracket is related to the class
```

Comment: two functions are out side the class

Answer (score 0):

it is the question if you want to have functions get_sql() and get_data() as a methods inside the A class:

If yes the code from user2727841 will work after you add the round brackets to the function public static function _test:

```
public static function _test()
  {
  }
```

Your code will work too after you add the same brackets to the same function but your function get_sql() and get_data() are outside the class A.

**EDIT**
I thought that these function are outside the class A.
Please, add the round brackets to the public static function _test in the class A - it is syntax error - than I hope it will work.

Comment: the problem is the functions are outside the class

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing you are not returning anything from the `get_sql($id)` function.

Assuming you are returning something in your original code; I hope you are aware that the function is not part of the class (its defined outside the scope of the class). But for educational purposes you would call a static method within a class by doing:

```
$a = A::get_sql($id);
```

This would also mean the defining the function in the following manner:

```
  Class A{
          public static function get_sql($id){
            echo $id;
          }
      }
```